# How to query pairs with knex

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, knex.js

I have a simple table (PostgreSQL) which contains two integer columns, say, `idx` and `idy`. I would like to use knex in order to query it to obtain all rows corresponding to a prescribed list of combinations `idx/idy`, e.g., to generate a query such as:

```
select * from "datatable" where (idx, idy) IN (('1', '10'), ('2', '20'))
```

Knex does offer the [`whereIn`](http://knexjs.org/#Builder-whereIn) method, nevertheless it seems that it does not support multiple columns. I managed to achieve the result with:

```
const knex_conf = require('./knexfile');
const knex = require('knex')(knex_conf.development);
const pgFormat = require('pg-format');

const pairs = [ [1, 10], [2, 20] ];

var P = knex.table('datatable').whereRaw(`(idx,idy) IN ${pgFormat('(%L)',pairs)}`).toSQL();
console.log(P.sql);
```

but I was wondering whether there would be a more elegant solution (without the need to use [`pg-format`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg-format) or similar "external" tools).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually knex already support this one:

https://runkit.com/embed/f2wym1fwfrn1

```
const Knex = require('knex');
const knex = Knex({
  client: 'pg'
});
const pairs = [ [1, 10], [2, 20] ];
knex('datatable').whereIn(['idx','idy'], pairs).toSQL();
```

Comment: perfect, that seems to be exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

Knex doesn't require you to use the 'query builder' functions.  In fact, as queries get more complicated, I would highly recommend to NOT use it... you'll spend far more time trying to glue all the functions together correctly vs just writing out the SQL by yourself.  Let's face it, at the end of the day, knex is just spitting out sql for you anyhow.  That said, something like this should work:

```
return knex.raw(`
    select *
    from datatable
    where (idx, idy) IN ((1, 10), (2, 20)....)
`);
```

Comment: And this is a great example how to start writing SQL injection bugs to your code, unless you are really just passing predefined ids to your query. I would strongly suggest against using knex.raw. Usually it is not really that hard to write even quite complicate queries in query builder format. Just add knex.raw to those parts of queries where it is really necessary.

Comment: You can add parameter binding to this query too.  Yes, granted doing it this way if the input was coming from a user, would definitely not want to do it this way (that is, without doing the param binding).

Comment: Also result from knex.raw is slightly more inconvenient to work with in comparison to query builder, which extracts rows from the data returned from driver.